# Trying to use ViewModels inside of another ViewModel, Errors with LifecycleObserver and Ownership (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, viewmodel

Im trying to get some data out of other ViewModels inside another ViewModel to make my code smaller, but im having a problem trying to implement what already worked on a fragment or in a activity, this is what i got:

```
class ObraConMediaViewModel(private val context: ViewModelStoreOwner,
                        private val id: Int): ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {

var allObras: LiveData<ArrayList<ObraConMedia>>

private lateinit var viewModelobras: ViewModelObras
private lateinit var viewModelMediaObra: ViewModelMediaObra

val repositoryobras =ObrasRepository()
val repositoryMediaObra = MediaObraRepository()

val viewModelFactoryobras = ViewModelFactoryObras(repositoryobras)
val viewModelMediaObraFactory = ViewModelMedIaObraFactory(repositoryMediaObra)

init{
    viewModelobras = ViewModelProvider(context, viewModelFactoryobras)
        .get(ViewModelObras::class.java) // requireActivity() when called
    viewModelMediaObra = ViewModelProvider(context, viewModelMediaObraFactory)
        .get(ViewModelMediaObra::class.java)

    viewModelobras.getObras(id)
    viewModelobras.myResponse.observe(this , Observer { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            Log.d("Response", response.body()?.ans?.get(0)?.autor)
            Log.d("Response", response.body()?.ans?.get(1)?.autor)
        }else{
            Log.d("Response", response.errorBody().toString())
        }})

    viewModelMediaObra.getMediaObra(Constantes.PRUEBA_ID)
    viewModelMediaObra.myResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            Log.d("Response", response.body()?.ans?.get(0)?.filePath)

        }
    })
}}
```

I was having trouble with the Observer but **extending** the class to **LifecycleObserver** fixed it, i have no idea if this will even work but the only error that i have right now its the owner of the .observe(**this**,....), i dont seem to find a way to pass a lifecycleowner from the **fragment** to this viewmodel. All the variables i need to make this viewmodel work are inside those two responses. If this is a very bad way to do it please tell me. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to have ViewModel inside another viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly note that above approach is not correct.
One should not create a instance of `ViewModel` inside another `ViewModel`.
There is a possibility that one `ViewModel` may get destroyed before another. This will lead to garbage reference and memory leaks.

I would recommend you to create the instance of both `View Models` in an `Activity`**/**`Fragment` and then call respective methods of `ViewModel` from `Activity`**/**`Fragment`.

Also, as you want to make your code smaller and concise, I highly recommend you `Shared ViewModel`.
This `Shared ViewModel` can be used by two fragments.
Please refer to this [**link**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)